# unable to resolve the column name from csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, gitlab

I am using the below code to get the list of Data however column is not being resolved, it throws an error **KeyError: 'Names'**

```
import csv

    # Open test.csv file in read mode
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        data = [row['Names'] for row in reader]
    print(data)
```

For example, if the test.csv file contained the following data:

```
Names
John
Mary
Smith
paul
```

The resulting data list should be:

```
['John', 'Mary', 'Smith', 'paul']
```

Note, I have only one column as shown in the example, this code runs well in my VM however it does not work if I run it as a pipeline in Gitlab. Also  Gitlab throws an error(as shown below) in repository if I open this csv file

```
Failed to render the CSV file for the following reasons:
  
      Unable to auto-detect delimiter; defaulted to ","
```

Answer (score 1):

You explained that test.csv starts with

> ```
> Name
> John
> ```

but I think you intended `Names` there,
to match your code.

---

> Gitlab throws an error

That looked more like a warning to me.
It appears you still get your `data` list,
just with some extra `sys.stderr` noise.

Consider using `import warnings`
if you'd like to suppress such noise.

---

You are using different CSV readers,
or different versions of readers,
in the different environments.
Strive to use the identical version in each,
so you will get identical behavior.
Also verify that test.csv is identical in each,
perhaps using /usr/bin/shasum.

---

Your current CSV reader apparently
wants to auto-detect column separators.
So give it some to detect.
Append a harmless `,` comma to each line,
which increases the column count by one.
Final column always has an empty value.

```
$ sed -i '' 's/$/,/' test.csv
```

(On Linux, unlike Mac, there's no need for that initial blank file extension when doing an in-place edit, so `sed -i 's/$/,/' test.csv` suffices.)

---

Some folks have reported that file corruption
can produce that "Unable to auto-detect delimiter"
warning.

Eyeball your file with `cat -n *.csv`
or the more detailed `cat -tevn *.csv`
to verify that each line contains
the proper number of fields.

Or have a program do it:

```
    with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        n = len(next(reader))
        print(f"Each row should have {n} fields.")
        for row in reader:
            assert n == len(fields), fields
```

Be especially wary of an extra blank line
at start or end of file.

---

Instead of

```
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

consider explicitly using

```
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter="\n")
```

so no auto-detection will be needed.

---

Using cPython 3.10.8 I was unable to
[reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the symptom using this:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO("Names\n\n\nAlice\nBob" + "\n" * 6)
reader = csv.DictReader(file)
for row in reader:
    print(len(row), row)
```

Comment: sorry for the typo in the question, the column name is "Names"